# Finding a coefficient of a unknown to have different solutions in a system

Tags: linear-algebra

I am beginning to learn elementary row operations. I am resolving the following system of linear equations.

---

2x + 2y + 3z = 0

4x + 8y + 12z = -4

6x + 2y + hz = 4

---

By using the method of row operations, I finally got the following result.

---

4y + 6z = -4

x + 2y + 3z = -1

( h - 3 )z = 8

---

Which means z equals 8/(h-3).

Is my calculation correct?

If h equals  3, does that means the value of z is undefined and the system has no solution?

For what values of h will the system have a unique solution and infinitely many solutions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $h=3$ then your equation $(h-3)z=8$ does not have a solution. Hence, the original system of equations does not have a solution.

If $h\neq3$, then you can uniquely solve for $z$, namely $z=8/(h-3)$. Substituting this into $4y+6z=-4$ yields a unique value for $y$, and substituting the derived values for $z$ and $y$ into $x+2y+3z=-1$ yields a unique value for $x$. Hence, if $h\neq3$, then the original system has a unique solution.

There is no value of $h$ for which the system has infinitely many solutions.